# add popup across ASP.NET websites without duplicating the code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am completely new to ASP.NET and C#.I was working with Java earlier.I have a requirement where I need to add a popup screen across different website deployed over IIS. The pop-up will gather email address and windows logon id of the user and will store it in the database.

I am wondering if there is a way which will help me in hooking up this requirement without the need to copy paste it across multiple websites.I googled a bit and found three things Custom Library, Custom Control and Assembly.

I am completely new to these concepts.Would someone please tell me which option is the best one because it is too confusing to decide which one I should use.I don't have any experience in .NET related terms.I am using .NET 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are looking for a custom control:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zt27tfhy(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zt27tfhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)